# writing to a m3u file with python

Tags: python, regex, scrape

I did this script I try to write what I request with regex when it comes to writing to a file `'w'` writes only last entry I try (`'w'`, `'wb'`, `'w+'`) all off them writes last entry where I do wrong?

```
#-*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import urllib2,urllib
import re
import os
import sys

value=[]
url='https://www.youtube.com/feeds/videos.xmlchannel_id=UCHXdylbsyDVN4UO2Fv8Cgm&API'
req = urllib2.Request(url)
req.add_header('User-Agent', 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_2) AppleWebKit/537.75.14 (KHTML,like Gecko) Version/7.0.3 Safari/573.75.14')
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
link=response.read()
response.close()
match=re.compile('<entry>\n  <id>.+?</id>\n  <yt:videoId>(.+?)</yt:videoId>\n  <yt:channelId>.+?</yt:channelId>\n  <title>(.*?)\(HD\)</title>').findall(link)
for videoid,isim in match:
    #print videoid,isim

    name='#EXTINF:-1 ,'+isim+'\n'
    link='plugin://plugin.video.youtube/play/?video_id='+videoid+'\n'
    value.append((str(name), str(link)))   

    for name,link in value:
        #print name,link
        with open('C:\\Users\\dir\\Desktop\\muhtesem_yuzyil_kosem.m3u', 'wb+') as f:
            f.write(name)
            f.write(link)
            f.seek(0)  # Important: return to the top of the file before reading, otherwise you'll just read an empty string
            data = f.read() # Returns 'somedata\n'
            f.flush()
            f.close()
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you just need to change `w` to `a`. `w` replaces whole content of the file and I guess you want to append to your file an item.

Comment: Try to use `r+b` instead.

Comment: in result i got 4 item i need 'w' to write all items don't know why it only write's 1

Comment: delimitry i try your suggestion same thing write's only 1 item

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few issues with your data writing code:

1. You open file in loop, for every `value` item found
2. You open file for writing only
3. You deliberately change internal filehandle position to beginning of file on each iteration, only to read entire file and `flush` what was left. This is not dangerous, only unnecessary. But you could take some time to review what you know about file operations.
4. You use `with` statement, which automatically closes filehandle, but then call `close()` nevertheless

There is nothing wrong with opening file for writing only if you do it once, and then loop over your values list:

```
with open('C:\\Users\\dir\\Desktop\\muhtesem_yuzyil_kosem.m3u', 'wb') as f:
       for name,link in value:
            f.write(name)
            f.write(link)
```

Or you can open file on each iteration, but then make sure that you open file for reading and writing:

```
 for name,link in value:
        with open('C:\\Users\\dir\\Desktop\\muhtesem_yuzyil_kosem.m3u', 'r+b') as f:
            f.seek(0)  # Important: return to the top of the file before reading, otherwise you'll just read an empty string
            data = f.read() # Returns 'somedata\n'
            # make sure that data is written only after cursor was positioned after current file content
            f.write(name)
            f.write(link)
```

Comment: that was great explanation Miroslaw zelewski sort it out  best regards

Comment: @MuratYilmaz if you have found that my answer solves your problem, please [accept it](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) ([visual guide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)). Just click a tick icon on the left side of my answer.